# How to retrain a model that was saved using the tf.saved_model.save() function in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am building a Neural Machine Translator for English to Konkani (a local language) language using the Transformer architecture proposed by (Vaswani et, al. 2017). I am following the tutorial code from https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer. I have trained the model and used the `tf.saved_model.save()` method to save the model files locally.

I now want to retrain that saved model on a new dataset that I have gathered recently, but I've realised that after loading the model using the `tf.saved_model.load()` method, I am not able to train it again as the loaded model now lacks the necessary method `model.fit()` .

Here is a part of the model training code:

```py
class Transformer(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, *, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff,
               input_vocab_size, target_vocab_size, dropout_rate=0.1):
    super().__init__()
    self.encoder = Encoder(num_layers=num_layers, d_model=d_model,
                           num_heads=num_heads, dff=dff,
                           vocab_size=input_vocab_size,
                           dropout_rate=dropout_rate)

    self.decoder = Decoder(num_layers=num_layers, d_model=d_model,
                           num_heads=num_heads, dff=dff,
                           vocab_size=target_vocab_size,
                           dropout_rate=dropout_rate)

    self.final_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(target_vocab_size)

  def call(self, inputs):
    # To use a Keras model with `.fit` you must pass all your inputs in the
    # first argument.
    context, x  = inputs

    context = self.encoder(context)  # (batch_size, context_len, d_model)

    x = self.decoder(x, context)  # (batch_size, target_len, d_model)

    # Final linear layer output.
    logits = self.final_layer(x)  # (batch_size, target_len, target_vocab_size)

    try:
      # Drop the keras mask, so it doesn't scale the losses/metrics.
      # b/250038731
      del logits._keras_mask
    except AttributeError:
      pass

    # Return the final output and the attention weights.
    return logits
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#...<code to define optimizers and loss functions>...

# This Class acts as an interface for the Transformer
class Translator(tf.Module):
  def __init__(self, context_tokenizers, target_tokenizers, transformer):
    self.context_tokenizers = context_tokenizers
    self.target_tokenizers = target_tokenizers
    self.transformer = transformer

  def __call__(self, sentence, max_length=MAX_TOKENS): #max_length=MAX_TOKENS
    assert isinstance(sentence, tf.Tensor)
    if len(sentence.shape) == 0:
      sentence = sentence[tf.newaxis]

    sentence = tokenize(sentence,self.context_tokenizers).to_tensor()

    encoder_input = sentence

    # As the output language is English, initialize the output with the
    # English `[START]` token.

    start_end = tokenize('',self.target_tokenizers)[0]
    start = start_end[0][tf.newaxis]
    end = start_end[-1][tf.newaxis]

    output_array = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int64, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    output_array = output_array.write(0, start)

    for i in tf.range(max_length):
      output = tf.transpose(output_array.stack())
      predictions = self.transformer([encoder_input, output], training=False)

      # Select the last token from the `seq_len` dimension.
      predictions = predictions[:, -1:, :]  # Shape `(batch_size, 1, vocab_size)`.

      predicted_id = tf.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)

      # Concatenate the `predicted_id` to the output which is given to the
      # decoder as its input.
      output_array = output_array.write(i+1, predicted_id[0])

      if predicted_id == end:
        break

    output = tf.transpose(output_array.stack())
    # The output shape is `(1, tokens)`.

    text = self.target_tokenizers.detokenize(output)

    tokens = tf.gather(target_vocab, output)

    # `tf.function` prevents us from using the attention_weights that were
    # calculated on the last iteration of the loop.
    # So, recalculate them outside the loop.
    self.transformer([encoder_input, output[:,:-1]], training=False)
    attention_weights = self.transformer.decoder.last_attn_scores

    joined_text = tf.strings.reduce_join(text[0][1:-1], separator=' ', axis=-1)
    return joined_text, tokens, attention_weights
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

class ExportTranslator(tf.Module):
  def __init__(self, translator):
    self.translator = translator

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)])
  def __call__(self, sentence):
    (result,
     tokens,
     attention_weights) = self.translator(sentence, max_length=MAX_TOKENS)

    return result
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

transformer = Transformer(
    num_layers=num_layers,
    d_model=d_model,
    num_heads=num_heads,
    dff=dff,
    input_vocab_size=context_vocab_size,
    target_vocab_size=target_vocab_size,
    dropout_rate=dropout_rate)

transformer.compile(
    loss=masked_loss,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    metrics=[masked_accuracy])

# training the model on the training data for some epochs
transformer.fit(train_batches,
                epochs=20,
                validation_data=val_batches,
                callbacks=[
                  tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=3)],
                )

translator = Translator(context_tokenizer, target_tokenizer, transformer)

exp_translator = ExportTranslator(translator)

#saving the model
tf.saved_model.save(exp_translator, export_dir=MODEL_SAVED_FILES)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#loading a saved model
reloaded = tf.saved_model.load(MODEL_SAVED_FILES)
```

Here's the error I get when I try to retrain the model using the following code:

```py
reloaded = tf.saved_model.load(MODEL_SAVED_FILES)

#retraing the model on new dataset
reloaded.translator.transformer.fit(train_batches,
                epochs=20,
                validation_data=val_batches,
                callbacks=[
                  tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=3)],
                )
```

The error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-41-ad1b625ff6c0> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 #retraing the model on new dataset
----> 2 reloaded.translator.transformer.fit(train_batches,
      3                 epochs=20,
      4                 validation_data=val_batches,
      5                 callbacks=[

AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

After reading the documentation I've realised that when saving the model in the above method, the `model.fit()` and other methods are not saved hence they are not callable.

I need help in finding a way to retrain my saved model, It is not feasible for me to train a new model on a combined dataset as It will take up lot of time and I have very limited resources. I have been looking up on the web for days but couldn't find a solution. Any help in this regards will be appreciated!